# Radius of sphere in which a tetrahedron can be inscribed

Tags: geometry, number-theory, contest-math, solid-geometry

> Find, with proof, all positive integers $N$ for which the sphere centered at the origin of radius $N$ has an inscribed regular tetrahedron whose vertices have integral coordinates.

Clearly if $N=3m^2$ there is such a tetrahedron; consider the vertices $(m,m,m), (m,-m,-m), (-m,-m,m), (-m,m,-m)$. Now suppose $Q_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i)$ for $1\leq i\leq 4$ are the vertices of an inscribed regular tetrahedron.

Here I'm supposing the centroid is the intersection of the line segments from vertices to the centroid of the opposite face (analogous to the centroid of a triangle being the intersection of the medians).

Why must it be the case that the center of the tetrahedron equals the center of the sphere? I think one way to prove this is to use vectors and prove that the vector sum of the 4 vectors with one endpoint at the origin and the other at a vertex of the tetrahedron is the zero vector.

In particular, I'm not sure why for a tetrahedron with vertices $A,B,C,D$, we have that the coordinates of the centroid/center is $\frac{A+B+C+D}4$. I can show that the point $O = \frac{A+B+C+D}4$ divides the line segments joining vertices to the centroid of the opposite face in the ratio $3:1$, but how does that show that $O$ is the centroid of the tetrahedron?

Why is it the case that the four vertices $Q_i$ along with the four vertices $R_i = (-x_i, -y_i, -z_i)$ form the vertices of an inscribed cube in the sphere?

I know the side length of the cube is $2(\frac{N}3)^{1/2}$ and so its volume is $8(N/3)^{3/2}$.

Why is this volume an integer? If so, that'll suffice to prove that $N = 3m^2$ for some integer $m$ because then $(N/3)^3$ would have to be a perfect square, which implies $N/3$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Reference: Putnam 2021 A3

Comment: Did you watch this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDj9cMT2K3E

Comment: And, by the way, $N$ is the SQUARED radius of the sphere.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca yes I know that. Could you provide a formal proof for why the centroid is equal to the origin? I know why it holds intuitively? Also you can assume the centroid's coordinates are the average of the vertex coordinates; I've seen a proof of that using vectors.

Comment: If a figure has some kind of symmetry, then its centroid lies on the locus of the invariant points under that symmetry. A regular tetrahedron is symmetric for a rotation of 120° about one of its heights, hence its centroid lies at the intersection of its heights.

Comment: Please stop the excessive use of blockquotes.  Not only does the question lack context, it also is way too unfocused: I count at least six questions.  Pease focus on one question at a time.  This site does not invited elaborate, extended, blog-style questions.